# unable to install c50 package in r in windows 10, i tried installing through the online .tar.gz files

Tags: r, windows, installation, package

if i try to run

```
library('C50')
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘C50’ in loadNamespace(i,
>   c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  there is no package
>   called ‘libcoin’ >
>
> install.packages("C50", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/balaj/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘C50’
>     These will not be installed

Comment: So you got a message that you needed the tools for compiling packages from source. Do you have those tools? If not, have you looked for them? If you have them, then you should provide details.

Comment: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows

Comment: Also, you may need package `libcoin` first?

Comment: I had the same issue and it worked

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment, this did the trick for me:

```
install.packages('libcoin', dependencies = T)
install.packages('C50', dependencies = T)
```